# Split rows by name

Tags: c#, crystal-reports, dataset

My stored procedure gets info from SQL DB. Now I want to add the info to a crystal report and display the PDF with all the details.

I use Visual Studio with Crystal reports installed, coding in C# using Dataset to get my info from SQL. The info is a list of names with 3 other details that goes with those names (columns). At times it can be one name as a result, or it can be 3 names as a result.

My aim is to have a table on the report, and each table row lists a name in the first column, then in the 3 consecutive columns its corresponding details. Same look to the SQL table you get when pulling the info.

To setup the individual columns is easy, drag each field onto the report. But how can I split the names so that I have one name listed per table row? This is the result from query:

[image]

I want to populate it into my Crystal form which looks like this:

[image]

Comment: can you show some example what you want or share some graphic so its easy to understand what you need?

Comment: In this case also you can drag the field and will behave the same what you expect I think.

Comment: From what I have used so far one can only drag the column names onto the form where you want that data to be displayed. Will try again to see if I can go deeper into the column name as well and then drag rows.

Comment: This is exactly what CP is supposed to do. Just drag your result from your database expert to your report details section like you expect : name info1 info2 info3 and that's all .. And add some lines to make it look like an array.

Comment: Under Data Fields I can only drill down to column names that is in my Dataset. Can't go to rows.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I have ended up with was to create a sub report, place it on top of the table I have created in my second picture. Then added the columns to the sub-report, took away any borders. And then between the container size on the report and with the paragraph options of the container I adjusted the line spaces. Now if I have more than one row in the list, it appears on each line as needed.